# What is the difference between 74HC595N and 74HC595B1R shift registers?

Tags: shift-register, 74hc595

They seem pretty the same, but B1R version is almost twice cheaper (at least in my country, and I don't know what are the manufacturers).

Comment: The letter suffix on an IC part number generally specifies the package - and these package codes vary between manufacturers.  It looksllike B1R is SGS-Thompson's code for a normal DIP package.  N is Texas Instrument's code for the sasme package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of manufacturer and specifications. The B1R suffix identifies a part made by STMicroelectronics, while an N suffix suggests a number of different possible manufacturers. The STM part is significantly slower than other makers' versions (55 MHz typ @ 5V for STM, 91 MHz typ @ 4.5V for SGThompson, for instance). At a guess, the STM part has a significantly smaller die than others, which limits the output drive into real loads, and produces a slower unit. But the smaller die allows lower cost.

Comment: Not sure anyone would really use 74hc at > 50MHz would they?